# VHDL need time delay in sequential CASE statement list

Tags: vhdl, fpga

I have an 8051 core running as the top level main module in my FPGA. I then have an I2C  routine (Im only doing 8051 master to LED display slave here) instantiated here as well. The 8051 sends parallel I2C address and data to the I2C routine and out comes the I2C data to my Salela scope. It works, BUT, Im having a problem and I need a time delay and just dont understand how to accomplish this. This is not for test bench or modelsim, this is for real. When the I2C routine is busy it makes the 'busy' bit high and the 8051 polls this and when the busy bit goes low the 8051 then sends the next 8 bits of parallel data to the I2C routine. The problem is the I2C routine toggles this 'busy' bit way too fast and the 8051 cant get its data to the I2C routine in time. I need the I2C routine sit and wait for a little while right after the busy bit goes low. Here is where I need it.

```
WHEN slv_ack2 =>                  
            IF(ena = '1') THEN                  
              busy <= '0';     -- I2C routine sets busy bit to low for 8051 to send data

              I need to wait here for 1 full second all the time when at this step

              
              addr_rw <= addr & rw;          
              data_tx <= data_wr;            
              IF(addr_rw = addr & rw) THEN   
                sda_int <= data_wr(bit_cnt); 
                state <= wr;                 
              ELSE                           
                state <= stop;              
              END IF;
              
WHEN wr =>                         -
            busy <= '1';                     
            IF(bit_cnt = 0) THEN             
              sda_int <= '1';                
              bit_cnt <= 7;                  
              state <= slv_ack2;             
            ELSE                             
              bit_cnt <= bit_cnt - 1;        
              sda_int <= data_tx(bit_cnt-1); 
              state <= wr;                   
            END IF;
```

Yes, I found a beautiful counter, and I can clearly see what it does, but where do I insert it and how to use it? Ok, I am new to VHDL/FPGA's but about 4 weeks now so still learning, syntax and placement is my biggest obstical so far.

```
      PROCESS (timer)
BEGIN
IF (clk12'EVENT AND clk12 = '1') THEN
    counter <= counter + '1';
    if( counter = 2 ) then
        SIGNAL_COUNTED <= '1';
        counter <= "0";
    else
        SIGNAL_COUNTER <= '0';
    end if;
END IF;
END PROCESS;
```

So what I want to do is this but I know it doesn't work that way. Where do I put it to make it work?

```
WHEN slv_ack2 =>                  
            IF(ena = '1') THEN               
              busy <= '0';
              
              

                  PROCESS (timer)
BEGIN
IF (clk12'EVENT AND clk12 = '1') THEN
    counter <= counter + '1';
    if( counter = 1 ) then
        SIGNAL_COUNTED <= '1';
        counter <= "0";
    else
        SIGNAL_COUNTER <= '0';
    end if;
END IF;
END PROCESS;


              
              addr_rw <= addr & rw;          
              data_tx <= data_wr;            
              IF(addr_rw = addr & rw) THEN   
                sda_int <= data_wr(bit_cnt); 
                state <= wr;                 
              ELSE                           
                state <= stop;              
              END IF;
              
WHEN wr =>                         -
            busy <= '1';                     
            IF(bit_cnt = 0) THEN             
              sda_int <= '1';                
              bit_cnt <= 7;                  
              state <= slv_ack2;             
            ELSE                             
              bit_cnt <= bit_cnt - 1;        
              sda_int <= data_tx(bit_cnt-1); 
              state <= wr;                   
            END IF;
```

Comment: You'll need a counter to wait for a time period.

Answer (score 1):

When you write VHDL you need to remember you are describing hardware so it is helpful to think of what the underlying circuit would be. In this case, you are trying to implement a sleep type function so you basically want your FSM to sit there doing nothing until the counter has timed out.

To do this, you need to add another state which waits for the counter to reach 0 (assuming you use a down counter to implement the counter). For example:

```
WHEN slv_ack2 =>                  
    IF(ena = '1') THEN                  
         busy  <= '0';
         state <= sleep;
    END IF;

WHEN sleep =>
    IF (timer = 0) THEN
        state        <= setup_write;
        enable_timer <= '0';
    ELSE
        enable_timer <= '1';
    END IF;

WHEN setup_write =>
    addr_rw <= addr & rw;          
    data_tx <= data_wr;            
    IF(addr_rw = addr & rw) THEN   
        sda_int <= data_wr(bit_cnt); 
        state <= wr;                 
    ELSE                           
        state <= stop;              
    END IF;
```

For the counter code, you can't place a process block inside of another process block. So you need to move it outside of the case statement. You also only want it to be actively counting when you are actually in the sleep state, so you will need to add an enable signal to it.